# Can basic app-usage statistics be obtained without an Azure subscription?

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-store, windows-dev-center

Is there any way to enable app-usage statistics without an Azure account just like we get it for crash reports?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement some kind of analytics service, like Google Analytics. The store provides only download and crash stats.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Microsoft [HockeyApp](https://www.hockeyapp.net/features/). As of March 2016 Microsoft announced that they are [transition mobile and desktop apps diagnostics from Application Insights to HockeyApp](https://www.hockeyapp.net/blog/2016/03/11/welcome-application-insights-users.html).

Hockey app supports sign via:

- ***Social Logins*** - Facebook, Twitter, Google and Microsoft (Personal/Work/School)
- ***Enterprise*** - Azure Active Directory (AAD) integration.

Feature - [User Metrics](https://www.hockeyapp.net/features/user-metrics/)

> Understand user behavior to improve your app. Track app adoption
>   through daily active users, monthly active users, and net new users.
>   Measure customer engagement through session count and verify your apps
>   reliability day by day with Crash Free Users.

[Nuget SDK's](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/hockeyapp) are available for various Windows and Xamarin platforms.